# Track page navigation of PDF being displayed in WebView of android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm displaying PDF in webview using google docs. Is there any way to know when user moves to next page?

My requirement is that I have an agreement begin displayed in PDF format through `WebView`, now when user moves to next page a `CheckBox` should appear, so I want to track page change.

Description of my scenario:

In image below, a PDF of ten pages is being displayed using `WebView`, now when user turns to next page using arrows present on right top, I need to know the change of event.

[image]

I tried to use `onProgressChanged()`, but it didn't help.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
             // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PAge change detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
           }
         });
```

I also tried using `onLoadResource()`,`shouldInterceptRequest()`, both of them didn't work.

Comment: Why not display the agreement before displaying the pdf at all?

Comment: @GabeSechan the agreement itself is in PDF format.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why shouldoverrideurl and onProgressChanged does not getting called when you try to load another page but the other work around it you can override the method :

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("URL","Load Resource"+ url);
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
}
```

it will show the url with pagenumber below it the url :

```
06-20 11:40:37.980: D/URL(5276):https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http%3A%2F%2F182.73.10.196%3A8001%2Fql%2FUnsignedAgreement%2Fexample.pdf&docid=a6653aac025f0eccbc5f96226923c79a&a=bi&pagenumber=2&w=253
```

in this string you have the pagenumber you can write logic around it to achieve what you need.

Comment: yes, when pdf is loaded for first time, but not when navigated to next page.

Comment: yes, by clicking button present on top right, I don't have control on those buttons.

Comment: `onLoadResource()` loads only once per URL. So if I want to reload the same url in same webview, the method fails.

Comment: Just because it cashes.. The mechanism of Google Docs is , It actually get the document , Convert it into images and gives back to Webview with Navigation Control. When you click on next button , It loads the next page as a resource and caches it. Figure is there any way not to cache those resources.

Comment: Yes, exactly that's how google docs work!! Isn't there any option to clear cache? I tried `clearHistory()` too.. but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

you could use `onJsBeforeUnload` this will tell you when user is navigating away from the current page. 
Returning false will stop navigation and returning true will allow navigation. 
Or handle it the way which suits your need.

```
public boolean onJsBeforeUnload(WebView view, String url, String message,
        JsResult result) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where do I call this method?